# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Scrolltotop' in '/opt/build/repo/src'

Tags: reactjs, import, deployment, continuous-deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy my site to netlify but i keep getting this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Scrolltotop' in
> '/opt/build/repo/src'

i dont have this import statement anywhere in my code.
Screenshot
[image]

This is my import statement
[image]

On my localhost server i am  not getting any error. Why is the deployment failing?

UPDATE
I have corrected the filename casing in github ie from Scrolltotop.js to ScrollToTop.js but the error is not gone

Answer (score 0):

What Solved it for me was to move the folder up a directory. I simply changed the location of the folder and did a git push. You could also try renaming the folder and do a git push.